# Assigning a variable within a statement in liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is there a way to have a variable within a statement in liquid so that something like the following:

```
{% assign somevar = 'about-us' %}
{{ pages.somevar.content }}
```

would result in the same output as if you had originally used:

```
{{ pages.about-us.content }}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  You could perhaps try something like {{ pages.#{somevar}.content }}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That gives a parse error as follows: There were errors saving your file:
Variable '{{ pages.#{somevar}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/

Comment: So I don't think you are going to be able to do what you want. At least from what I understand you are trying to do in your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
{% assign somevar = 'about-us' %}
{{ pages.[somevar].content }}
```

That works fine for me...